# Any other mouse buttons pressed suppress MouseButtons.Left [C#]

Tags: c#, mouseevent

Whenever you hold any other mouse button when the program is working it suppresses the work of it.
Etc. Holding right mouse button stops clicking.

```
bool mousdown = MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left;
                

                if (mousdown)
                {
                    mouse_event(LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    WaitMilliSec(clickDelay);          // CLICKS
                    mouse_event(LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
```

I have tried doing stuff like:

```
if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Right)
{
return;
}
```

But honestly I don't know how to prevent it.

Comment: _"Holding right mouse button stops clicking"_ - that's **by design**.  On Windows a "Mouse Click" is defined as _pressing down on the button, keeping it there for a minimum period, without moving the mouse too much and then releasing the button within the click limit_.  "Right Mouse Button Down" is not the same and means the user has continued to depress the button beyond the click limit.    In the latter scenario the user (hopefully) will release the button leading to a "Right button UP"

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        // do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think u understood what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

So instead of using

```
MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left
```

Use

```
(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) < 0);
```

Comment: Not the down-voter but it's not necessary to leap down to WIN32 level via p-invoke for this.